# Is there a way to force an attoparsec not to backtrack?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, backtracking, attoparsec

I've written some parsers using [Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) but only now realised that I don't always want them to backtrack on failure, but attoparsec parsers always backtrack on failure.

Is there a way to force a parser not to backtrack?

For example, this attoparsec parser will succeed when given the input "for":

```
string "foo" <|> string "for"
```

A parsec parser would not succeed on that input and I want to emulate this behaviour using an attoparsec parser.

Comment: Use the [`Data.Attoparsec.Text.Parsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-parsec-0.1.3/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text-Parsec.html) module which is precisely provided to make code compatible between Attoparsec and Parsec.

Comment: I wonder why you want that? It's often considered the most annoying feat of `Parsec` that you have to explicitly `try` everything to get backtracking on failure. The biggest reason not to backtrack seems clearer error messages, but Attoparsec doesn't give those anyway.

Comment: I ended up using [trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta) instead. Thanks for your help though.